# Simple margin-top / margin-left trouble

Tags: html, css

Enlighten me a question:

If I put a div inside another, in this second div I can't use the properties `margin-left` and `margin-top` without changing the position of parent div?

I need to use `padding` instead??

EXEMPLE:

FIDDLE WITH MARGINS: http://jsfiddle.net/zyEYj/1/

FIDDLE WITHOUT MARGINS: http://jsfiddle.net/zyEYj/2/

FIDDLE WITH PADDING INSIDE MOTHER DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/zyEYj/3/ (this is the final effect i want, but i need to use padding, and change the height of `#header`)

codes:

```
<div id="header" class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.asp"><img src="imagens/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
body{
background:#d3f1fc;        
}

#header{
    height:135px;
    background:#ee4b14;
    padding-top:35px;
    padding-left:21px;
}

.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
}

.logo{
    width:382px;
    height:114px;
    background:#FFCC00;
}​
```

Comment: Do you have any sort of contraints regarding those div? Or does everything works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is referred to as `margin collapse`. Two adjacent margins will collapse into one another, with the higher absolute value taking precedence.

This can be defeated either by separating the margins (via `padding` or `border` on the parent element), or by using `position: relative` on the child element, and adjusting its position that way.

### HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

#### Normal

```
/*
    these margins will collapse, and result in a total margin of 15px
*/
.parent
{
    margin: 5px;
}

.child
{
    margin: 15px;
}
```

#### Padding/Border solution

```
/*
    these margins will be separate, resulting in a total margin of 20px
    plus the border or padding of 1px
*/
.parent
{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 1px; /* or border: 1px; */
}

.child
{
    margin: 15px;
}
```

#### Position: relative solution

```
/*
    there is only one margin here, and the child
    is positioned relative to where it would usually be rendered
*/
.parent
{
    margin: 5px;
}

.child
{
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: The problem with your *relative solution* is that relative positioning also moves the bottom down 15px, potentially causing it to overlap any elements that are below `.child`.  You'll have to add some margin or padding along either the `.parent` or `.child` element.

Comment: works very well with this _relative solution_ ... thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behaivour. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html is a good reading to get a better understanding.

You will have to use `padding` on the parent to move the child's top.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/88ATa/

Best regards.
Jonas

Comment: Ok, but if I have another element that will be aligned at the top, without that padding?

Comment: @Preston Use position: relative; in combination with top: Xpx;

Comment: Exactly as @Dr.Flink saies. Or set a border on the parent :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it would be to put the `container` div in an absolute position, so that the inner div has its limits limited by the boundary of the container.
So juste adding

```
.container {
     position:absolute;
 }
```

will work. But for some reason, absolute positioning might not be what your looking for. It might change your page layout for example.

See : http://jsfiddle.net/zyEYj/13/